# PHP and Javascript triggered by events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-events

I'm making a web page in PHP and what I want to do, is a script that triggers only if a certain PHP condition are done. Here is my  code:

```
<div class="content" <?php echo $data_attributes; ?>>
 <?php foreach($slides  as $slide): ?>

    <?php if($slide['type'] == 'image'){
          $backgroundi = $slide['image_url'];
       ?>
<div class="fill" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $backgroundi;>);"></div>
     <?php }
        elseif($slide['type'] == 'custom'){ 
        echo 'jQuery(function($) {
        $(".bx-pager-item").find("a.bx-pager-link").addClass("text-info-slider");
       });';
       echo '</script>';?>
<div class="project-info">
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 project-text">
  <div class="project-body">
      <?php echo $slide['custom']; ?>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8 project-images"></div>
  </div>
  <?php }
   else{
    echo'Nothing Found';
   }endforeach; ?>
```

When is the first type:

```
if($slide['type'] == 'image'){
```

[image]

When it is the second type:

```
elseif($slide['type'] == 'custom'){
```

[image]

The class is

```
addClass("text-info-slider");
```

This is used for adding a different style, to the slider circles for a different post type. But when I wrote the script:

```
 echo 'jQuery(function($) {
        $(".bx-pager-item").find("a.bx-pager-link").addClass("text-info-slider");
       });';
       echo '</script>';?>
```

It affects all the type of files. I want to be affected only the type "CUSTOM".
Who can help me?

Comment: How would you rate your indentation style yourself from 1 - 10. Where 1 is terrible and 10 is perfect?

Comment: I would rate that a 0

Comment: If you want US to help YOU, then YOU have to help US by at least making the code you show us READABLE. Also if you make it readable **maybe you will be able to debug your own code**

Comment: sorry. I just added it quickly, and didn't made the indention. I usually use 6 for indetion #PeeHaa

Comment: Please include the output of your foreach loop so we can see what the slide type is for each of the slides.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your code

```
<div class="content" <?php echo $data_attributes; ?>>
    <?php 
        foreach($slides as $slide) 
        {
            if( $slide[ 'type' ] == 'image' )
            {
                $backgroundi = $slide[ 'image_url' ];
    ?>
    <div class="fill" style="background-image: url( <?php echo $backgroundi; ?> );"></div>  <!-- Missing the ? from the closing tag -->
        <?php 
            } 
            elseif( $slide[ 'type' ] == 'custom' ) 
            { 
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">';  // Missing the opening tag for the script
                echo 'jQuery(function($) {
                                $(".bx-pager-item").find("a.bx-pager-link").addClass("text-info-slider");
                            });';
                echo '</script>';
        ?>
    <div class="project-info">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 project-text">
            <div class="project-body">
                <?php echo $slide[ 'custom' ]; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8 project-images"></div>
    </div>
        <?php 
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Nothing Found';
            }
        }  // End Foreach
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: no, it's not there the problem, since the script is working. But I want it to be functional only in the type custom.